# How to start my android app at 12:00 AM every day, even if app is closed

Tags: java, android

I'm using the below code.
But it's not working as I expected.

```
AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyReciever.class);
intent.putExtra(ONE_TIME, Boolean.TRUE);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(),
        20*1000, pi);
```

This code will execute 20 sec once, but if I replace with 20*1000 by 24*60*60*1000, it will execute once per day.

But if I install 4:00 PM today, I think the logic which I wrote above wont execute 12:00 AM, because I have given per 24hrs once.

Can you please suggest me the right logic with good example.

Really appreciate your help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: when your app is running for first time get the time of day and calculate time remain to 12:00 am. after that create alarmmanager by that value for the first time.

Comment: first time get the time of day and calculate time remain to 12:00 am then use Calendar object to set exact time and then pass that to alarm manager (calendar.get time();)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

//Calculate now:

```
long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

//Calculate tomorrow in milliseconds:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1); // Add a day
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0); // Set to 12:00
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0); 
cal.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.PM);
long tomorrow = cal.getTimeInMillis();
```

//Calculate the interval between today and tomorrow

```
long interval = tomorrow - now;
```

Now replace 20*1000 with the interval.

Pay attention that you add a day to the calendar, so if you set the alarm at 8.00 in the morning - it will alarm the day after at 12.00.

Comment: do not forget that if you want that it work every day, you should create new alarm manager in the response result class of first alarm manager that its timer has been set to 24 hours (i hope that i am clear;)).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your valuable comment for my question.
Here is exact answer what i implemented for my app .With this logic my app exactly starts after 12:00 AM with the 10 minutes interval.It will keep on running for every 10 minutes.

Code as below

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0); // Set to 12:00
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0); 
long tomorrow = cal.getTimeInMillis();
AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyReciever.class);
intent.putExtra(ONE_TIME, Boolean.TRUE);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(),
10*60*1000, pi);
```

To stop keep on running, Android provides spl APIs to provide long interval as below
AlarmManager.Hour,Fifteenminutes,Halfday,etc,.

Thanks
Krishh